# Get attribute from a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I do create a field like this:

```
    $builder->add('new_item', 'text', array(
        'required' => false,
        'property_path' => false,
        'attr' => array('id' => $list_id),
            )
    );
```

How can I get the attribute `id` in the Method POST when the form is valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you create a hidden field for your value :

```
$builder->add('my_hidden_field', 'hidden', array(
    'data' => $list_id,
    'property_path' => false
    )
);
```

(Note: using the [`property_path`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html#property-path) option with the value `false` means it's not written to the object)

you cannot retrieve the `id` attribute of a field after its been `POST`ed to the server.